# How to include menu item in breadcrumb

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I've this breadcrumb I've created, where I would like to show it as

Home > Main menu > Sub menu

Where sub menu is connected to a node. So when a user click on node, it must show the breadcrumb of the above format.

I've done this, but it is only giving

Home > Sub menu

Menu is missing.

```
function basis_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  if (($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) && $variables['breadcrumb']) {
    $variables['breadcrumb'][] = array(
      'text' => $node->getTitle(),
      'url' => $node->URL()
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Menu Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If the url reflects the correct path, you can add this to your .theme file.

```
function hook_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  $variables['breadcrumb'] = array();
  $variables['node'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Link $link */
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $key => $link) {
    $variables['breadcrumb'][$key] = array('text' => $link->gettext(), 'url' => $link->getUrl()->toString());
  }

  // As of Drupal 8.1.3, core caches breadcrumb parent. This breaks what I'm trying to do. Good-bye to this caching rule.
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url';
}
```

EDIT

If the url is missing the 'Main menu' part, you can manually set the breadcrumb for any specific content type. Again in the theme file.

```
function hook_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  $variables['breadcrumb'] = array();
  $variables['node'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  $variables['type'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')->getType();

  switch($variables['type']) {

    case 'YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE':
      $variables['breadcrumb'] = array(
        array(
          'text' => 'Home',
          'url' => '/'
        ),
        array(
          'text' => 'Main menu',
          'url' => 'Main menu url'
        ),
        array(
            'text' => $variables['node']->getTitle(),
            'url' => $variables['node']->URL()
          ),
        );
      break;

    default:
      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Link $link */
      foreach ($variables['links'] as $key => $link) {
        $variables['breadcrumb'][$key] = array('text' => $link->gettext(), 'url' => $link->getUrl()->toString());
      }
      break;
  }

  // As of Drupal 8.1.3, core caches breadcrumb parent. This breaks what I'm trying to do. Good-bye to this caching rule.
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url';
}
```